# Ignore CSS declaration on a specific control

Tags: css, html

I have a checkbox `input` control and I have a CSS file which includes the following declaration:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}
```

I want this CSS to be be applied to any checkbox `input` element except one. How can I ignore this CSS rule(`display:none;`) on one of my controls?

Comment: You cannot have it *ignored*. You can only have it *overridden*. Or you can *modify* (if that’s an option) it so that it does not apply to a specific element. In both cases, the answer depends on how the element to be excepted can be identified. So this is almost an “unclear what you are asking” question, but there are now good alternative answers. Just note that they partly answer different questions, since the question was ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is target that specific checkbox and give it a `display` of `initial`.

You haven't provided any HTML so I'm going to have to make up a generic example:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"].bar {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="bar" />
<input type="checkbox" class="baz" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do something like:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:not(.this_one) {
  display: none;
}
```

**Note:** Replace this_one with the ID or class of the one you want to exempt(leave out)

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/1b6et7xs/)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a class to add this css property (and possibly others) and omit the class for the needed element

```
input[type="checkbox"].yourClass 
{
    display:none;
}

  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class = "yourClass"> I have a bike
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" class = "yourClass"> I have a bike
  <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> The one without the class
```

Comment: `.yourClass input[type="checkbox"]` selects the `input[type="checkbox"]` **child** of `.yourClass`. You'd need to use `input[type="checkbox"].yourClass` for the example you've provided.

Comment: yes, but if i have more then one CSS ruls in this CSS file and i dont want to change it, can i just add to this specific control rule that able me not inherit from css file on it

Answer (score 1):

As you can see by the other solutions, there are many ways to accomplish what you want. Another way is to use the "cascading" aspect of cascading style sheets by overriding the style within the element:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" style="display:initial" />
```